# PHP 5.4 - Variable defined by string and it's value set to NULL is not defined

Tags: php, php-5.4

Can anyone tell my why the variable defined by string does not exists?

```
$string = 'variable';
${$string} = NULL;

echo $variable;
```

> Variable $variable is not defined.

Comment: From the manual : `Returns TRUE if var exists and has value other than NULL, FALSE otherwise. ` [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

Comment: Mkay, but why the variable does not exists?

Comment: @KrzysztofTrzos ^ Did you read it? **and has value other than NULL** your variable is NULL, so it's false

Comment: I know how ISSET works. I only want to know WHY the variable is not defined, when I define it by the way like i showed?

Comment: Because `null` is a non-existant value

Comment: NULL is not variable..

Comment: if you want use NULL as variable enclose it with single quotes or double...

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.null.php

Comment: @user1844933 what are you talking about? If you want to use `null` use it as `null` and not as a string... `if ($var === null) doSthing();`

Comment: @DarkBee What would like to say, OP may want to use variable as blank or value of NULL, anyway its complicated to understand and to say ans... so that so many down voted....

Comment: I use `null` all the time in my code. Nothing wrong with that. The downvotes are there because OP did not read the manual proper/did not ask the question properly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78008/discussion-between-user1844933-and-darkbee).

Comment: As per your updated question, `echo $variable;`  should definitely not give you undefined `$variable` error because it is defined in the previous line.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

> isset — Determine if a variable is set and is not **NULL**

Since you set the variable to NULL like

```
$string = 'variable';
${$string} = NULL;
```

it will return **false**

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by others, `isset()` checks if the variable is set and is not `null`.

If you want to check if the variable is defined at all including the ones set as `null`,  you can use get_defined_vars() to get list defined variables and check if the variable name is there:

```
$string = null;
$string2 = '';

var_dump(array_key_exists('string', get_defined_vars())); // bool(true)
var_dump(array_key_exists('string2', get_defined_vars())); // bool(true)
var_dump(array_key_exists('string3', get_defined_vars())); // bool(false)
```

Answer (score -1):

An undefined variable in PHP has value NULL, therefore:

```
${$string} == $variable;
${$string2} == $variable2;

${$string2} == $variable2 == 'value'; // so isset returns TRUE
$variable == NULL; // so isset returns FALSE
${$string} == $variable == NULL; // so isset returns FALSE
```